# Can vulkan semaphores be used to wait for memory transfers?

Tags: c, vulkan

Suppose I have two command buffers: cb1, cb2.
If command buffer cb2 waits on cb1 execution using a semaphore. Does that imply that cb2 will only execute after all cb1 memory transfers are completed?

In other words, Do Vulkan semaphores also work as memory barriers?

Answer (score 4):

Vulkan specification [6.4.1. Semaphore Signaling](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-semaphores-signaling):

> When a batch is submitted to a queue via a queue submission, and it includes semaphores to be signaled, it defines a **memory dependency** on the batch, [...]

There are more details in that and the next (6.4.2. Semaphore Waiting & Unsignaling) chapter.